# Validator Error is removed in Angular Forms

Tags: angular, forms

I am trying to do two types of validations.

```
this.form= new FormGroup({
      initial: new FormControl (null, Validators.max(5))
});
```

If initial has a error because is less than 5 and I want to add a new error with:

```
setErrors({ 'customError': true });
```

The validator error is removed and it is only showed the custom error.

Could you help me?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Why not setting several Validators ? `initial: new FormControl (null, [Validators.max(5), Validators.min(5)])`

Answer (score 3):

setErrors is overwriting old errors, you need to take the old errors into account, two ways of doing it :

```
formControl.errors['MyNewError'] = { errorData: 'data' };
// Or
formControl.setErrors({ ...formControl.errors, 'MyNewError': { errorData: 'data' } });
```